# Is there a single mod that fixes many bugs in Dragon Age Origins?

Tags: mods, dragon-age-origins

The latest Dragon Age version for PC seems to still have a respectable number of bugs:

http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Bugs

I've seen some mods that can fix this or that bug, but I'm looking for a more comprehensive solution. Is there a single mod out there that fixes many bugs, or alternatively can someone link to / provide a list of mods that need to be installed for fixing most of the bugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single fix all bug for DA. First did you update to 1.04 patch? That will fix a lot of the bigger bugs, it won't fix all of them of course and some might never get fixed.

Go to [Dragon Age Nexus](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/search.php) for a number of mod fixes (search for fix or fixes) there's about 10-15 mods that do some fixes. Some are no longer needed as of 1.04.

Edit: Here's a list of the ones copied from the search results (not CATEGORY fix, just search for fix or fixes in the filename/description)

[Armor Rune Drop Fixes](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=954)
[Awakening Blackblade Armor Dragon Drop Fix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1112)
[Awakening Runes Fixes](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1020)
[BlackTemplarFix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=960)
[City Elf Romance Alienage Fix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=952)
[CrystalDragonFix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=972)
[Dragon Age Simple Fixes](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1601)
[Drain Life bugfix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1237)
[Endgame Dialogue and Epilogue Slide Fixes](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=513)
[Find Vitals Fix - Awakening](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1060)
[Golem Registry and Shapers Life Reward Fix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=335)
[Leliana Your Zevran Dialog Fix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=959)
[Morrigan Restoration Patch Dialog Fixpack](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1120)
[Non-Circle Origin Mage Dialogue Fixes](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1623)
[Plus Healing Received Fix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=573)
[Second Drain life bug fix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1172)
[VigilanceFixed](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=958)
[Zevran Dialog Fix](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=928)

NOTE: some of these MIGHT of been fixed in 1.04 so install that FIRST, then these (which won't hurt if they are fixed)

Comment: Bummer about no single fix. I'm looking for a list of those 10-15 mods that I do need to install... there are lots of mods in that nexus, and I weren't able to find any "fixes" category.

Comment: Ok I updated it but that's what search is for you know.

Comment: I recommend you add "@Oak" somewhere in your comment next time, otherwise it doesn't notify me - I only saw your edit now :)

Comment: @Oak ah good to know

Answer (score 2):

This Link gets all the bug fixes for the 1.04 Version.

http://www.nexusmods.com/dragonage/mods/1601/?

Installation is very easy, and fixes everything without any gameplay mods, just fixes the bugs like haste slowing down archery and attack speed with momentum. Im still wondering how on earth bioware didn't come up with a official fix / patch. Haste Slowing down attack speed.., what a Joke! They make great games but i guess they are a bit "hasty" to release them without proper testing.